# Android NDK debugging (project created with make i.e. Android.mk)

Tags: debugging, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I've spent way too much time until now so I need you help friends, here's the deal:
I need to have a native debugger to debug some C files I am creating in the project which use a prebuilt C library I have.
I can do the debugging with:

- the GDB right? nope! because it does not work with make files.
- the GDB and use the ndk-build script, fine, I can do that, but now I cannot include a search path into the script, I tried a cFlag, different things, does not work.

What should I do? how the ... should I debug my code and have some a search paths for the prebuilt library?

I hope I am clear, please ask questions, will answer any of them! Thanks friends.